# Neo4j...how to get a visual representation of my data?

Tags: database, nosql, neo4j, embedded-database

I have loaded an embedded instance of Neo4j with some data, and would like to know how I can now view this graph. I saw an intro video here: http://video.neo4j.org/m9FD/how-to-get-started-with-neo4j-119/. Here the guy opened an instance in his web browser via `Heroku` and was able not only see the data in the graph, but also enter new data and search for both `nodes` and `relationships`. How do I see the data I have entered into the graph-database?

```
graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( "var/graphDb" );
        registerShutdownHook(graphDb);

        WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper srv = new WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper( graphDb );
        srv.start();

        for (Statement s : statements){

            Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
            try{
                firstNode = graphDb.createNode();
                firstNode.setProperty("message", s.getFirstTerm());
                secondNode = graphDb.createNode();
                secondNode.setProperty( "message", s.getSecondTerm());

                relation = firstNode.createRelationshipTo(secondNode, s.getRelationshipType());
                //relation.setProperty("message", "crazy cruel");
                tx.success();
            }
            finally{
                tx.finish();
            }
        }
        srv.stop();

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could either

- fire up a server as part of your embedded instance, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/server-embedded.html
- use Neoclipse and point it to your (shut down) database, see http://vimeo.com/12014944 aand https://github.com/neo4j/neoclipse
- install Neo4j Server http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/server.html, point out your database and use the webadmin tool for visualization.

Would that work?

Comment: Thanks for responding Peter. I have been going through the docs for sometime now trying to figure this thing out. The documentation makes mention of a 'WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper' class. However this class is not recognized by eclipse, and does not appear to be part of the Neo4J1.7.2 distro. What should I use in its place? Here is a snippet of code I am working with...if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: couldnt figure out how to add code in a comment, so I added a snippet to my original post. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, so I figured out that the JAR I need is not included in the Commercial distro. Maybe it is in the Advanced? Neoclipse is cool and I got that working so I consider this an answer. Not for nothing though Peter, you guys could be a bit more descriptive about such things in your documentation. Thanks again!

Comment: the WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper is in the neo4j-server jar of the community distribution, you should be able to do it like http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/server-embedded.html ?

Comment: @PeterNeubauer the link for the neo4j embedded instance is dead.