# Show neo4j graph in eclipse

Tags: java, neo4j

I have created nodes and relationships in java class using Neo4j.
how can i represent those relationships in graph ? where to show them in graph like structure?

Please guide.

Comment: Plz add some code and ask specific questions.

Comment: See if this helps :- http://www.neo4j.org/develop/visualize

Comment: Seems like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043402/neo4j-how-to-get-a-visual-representation-of-my-data is your answer. Is this a duplicate question?